# how to use db.collection.createIndex method in flask pymnogo

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, flask

i want to use `db.collection.createIndex` method in my mongodb document but  i am getting `NameError: name 'db' is not defined`. how can i use this method in flask_pymnogo ?
 **Please help**

**Here's code**

```
@app.route('/insert')
def inserting_data():
    database = mongo.db.mylogin
    user_col = database.find({ "location": { "$nearSphere": { "$geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [21.0955, 81.0375]}, "$maxDistance":5000 } } })
    db.database.createIndex( { "location": "2dsphere" } )
    return list(user_col)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you might not have created the db object properly for initiating the connection to the database. like using these lines.

```
client = MongoClient('localhost',27017)
db = client.test_insert       ## name of the database
collection = db.test_dataset  ## name of the collection
```

Furthermore, the method for creating index in pymongo is create_index. You should do something like this

```
my_collection.create_index(keys, session=None, **kwargs)
```

You can have a look at the [documentation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html) here.

Comment: i want these configuration's for flask_pymongo